# How to add a User Control to a window at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, mvvm

I need to add a User Control to a window at runtime. Now my problem is that i need to instantiate the window first and then add the User Control to that window. After all this the window only will be shown

My thoughts was this:

Create the instance of the User Control first:

```
     string managedClassName = "SupplierModule.Views.SupplierInvoiceView, SupplierModule";

     var userControl = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(managedClassName));
```

Then create the window :

```
     NavigationWindow navigationWindow = new NavigationWindow();
```

and then add the User Control to the window.

So my problem is, how do i add this user control to the window?

I don't know if i have approached it in the right way. So if its wrong please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using WPF and MVVM

1- Define below code in the Xaml

```
<ContentControl
            Margin="10,0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Content="{Binding TableDetailsDataFormView}"/>
```

2- Define a TableDetailsDataFormView property in your ViewModel.

3- Assign the property TableDetailsDataFormView when you createded your ViewModel.

4- I am assuming that you have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged then called the appropiate method to notify the UI

Comment: My NavigationWindow is in a different project in my solution from where i am creating it now. Is there a reason why i can't access any methods or properties in the window?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `NavigationWindow`, you should use a page to which you add the user control. First create a `Page`, then set `Page.Content` to the user control and then use `Navigate(page)` to navigate to this page.